# Is it possible to get count of number of docs returned from find() query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to get count of data fetched from the database using find() query in mongoose. Now can anyone tell me can i do something like below or do i have to write other function to do that

```
merchantmodel.find({merchant_id: merchant_id, rating: {'$ne': -1 }, review: {'$ne': "" }}, {'review':1, '_id':0}, {sort: {time_at: -1}}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {

        } else {
            if (docs) {
                console.log(docs[1].review);
                console.log(docs.size()); // Here by writing something is it possible to get count or not
                res.json({success: 1, message : "Successfully Fetched the Reviews"});
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
console.log(docs.length);
```

The `docs` variable returned by the `find()` method is an array so **`docs.length`** would do the job.

The [mongodb native way](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) to do this would be:

```
db.collection.find( { a: 5, b: 5 } ).count()
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert returned value to array and then use length property

```
var query = { merchant_id : merchant_id, rating : { '$ne': -1 }, review: { '$ne': "" }}; 
var projection = { 'review':1, '_id':0 }; 
var options = { sort: { time_at: -1 } };
merchantmodel.find(query, projection, options).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        throw(err);
    }
    console.log(docs[1].review);
    console.log(docs.length);
    res.json({success: 1, message : "Successfully Fetched the Reviews"});
});
```